# What benefits are there to setting a home planet?

Tags: starbound

While in the space travel screen there was a button "Set Home Planet". When I set a planet to be my home, what happens to it?

Comment: Note that in the post-1.0 game this feature has been replaced with a more powerful "teleport bookmark" system using placed teleporters or racial flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current version of Starbound allows to teleport to home planet from ship.
[image]

Comment: How does it work when ship is on another planet's orbit? Once I tried to click this button, but nothing happened.

Comment: You need to set home planet first. There is button in navigation interface.

Answer (score 5):

Allows you to easily return to that planet if you go somewhere else

Comment: Can you expand a bit? How do you do that?

Comment: In the navigation menu there is an button that brings up your home planet. You then just hit go to head there.